# Replacing NA in my dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have called the indices of the Features for my train and test dataframe with NAs i want to replace as:

```
Catlist1=['FireplaceQu','BsmtQual','BsmtExpo','BsmtCond','BsmtFinType1','GarageFinish',
'GarageType','GarageCond','GarageQual','MasVnrType']
Catlist2=['FireplaceQu','BsmtQual','BsmtExpo','BsmtCond','BsmtFinType1','GarageFinish',
'GarageType','GarageCond','GarageQual','MasVnrType']
```

To replace the NAs i called:

```
for i in Catlist1:
   train_df.ix[pd.isnull(train_df[:,i]),i]=np.nanmedian(train_df.ix[:,i])
for i in Catlist2:
   test_df.ix[pd.isnull(test_df[:,i]),i]=np.nanmedian(test_df.ix[:,i])
```

And i got the error message:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I am not sure i understand this error message and what i may be doing wrong here. Thank You!

Comment: have you tried using the returned value of `pd.dropna(train_df.ix[:,i])`

Comment: that means some of the columns are not numeric or you have mixed types i.e. str and NaN. You could try `df.fillna(np.nanmedian(df))`